# How to use MS access connection string?

Tags: ms-access

Been searching on net over hours how to connect from MS access to .mdb stored on web server (http://domain.com/db.mdb).

Seems like I can connect using connection string such as listed here: connectionstrings.com/access/

Something like: Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=http://www.domain.com/db.mdb;

My problem is I don't know where to insert that piece of text. Can somebody point me to a tutorial or guide me trough?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is impossible. You can only establish an OLEDB connection to an Access database file that is:

- on a local drive, or
- on a Windows network (SMB) share

You cannot directly connect to an Access database over HTTP (nor would you want to). The closest you would get would be to have a web service running on the server that could accept requests and update the database for you.

Comment: Still, I'd like to know where to insert that connection string.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would connect one MDB to another.  It should give you an idea of where in your code you put your connection string, and how to use it:

```
Dim lPK As Long
Dim sLast As String
Dim sFirst As String
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sSQL As String

lPK = Me.ID
sLast = Me.LastName
sFirst = Me.FirstName

sSQL = "UPDATE tblMyOtherDatabaseTable " & _
 "SET [LastName] = '" & sLast & "', " & _
 "[FirstName] = '" & sFirst & "' " & _
 "WHERE ID = " & lPK

cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
 "Data Source=\my_path\MyOtherDatabase.mdb;" & _
 "User ID=userid;" & _
 "Password=password;"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sSQL, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```